# What is this structure called?

Tags: c#, recursion, linked-list, queue

I've been writing this data structure for a few days, and now I'm really curious about what it actually is, and to get some critique on my logic.

A branch, based on this usage, exists when a `HEAD` node contains at least one node of the same type referenced.

The purpose of the structure is to have branches that are arranged by type. Each node on the branch has a reference to the next node on the branch (always of the same type) and an entry point to a `Subdata` branch. `Subdata` in this case being an instance of a class that inherits from the `AchievementNode`. When `subdata` is added and it is the first of it's kind on that branch it has the `HEAD` tag applied to it, additionally, it also has a tag that contains the metadata of the type of data contained (to bypass the `typeof` calls).

Implementation:

```
public abstract class AchievementNode : ScriptableObject
{
    public enum NodeTypes
    {
        NONE   = 0x0,
        HEAD   = 0x1,
        TAIL   = 0x2,
        TYPE   = 0x4,
        DATA   = 0x8,
        LEVEL  = 0x16,
        GLOBAL = 0x32
    }

    public NodeTypes nodeType;

    public AchievementNode nextOfType;

    public AchievementNode headOfSubnode;

    public void OnEnable ()
    {
        hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
    }

    public virtual void Init(NodeTypes type, int enumData)
    {
        nodeType = type;
    }

    protected void AddNode(NodeTypes type, AchievementNode originNode, AchievementNode newNode)
    {
        //Create SubNode branch notch when types mismatch.
        if((originNode.nodeType & type) != type)
        {
            //If Has subNode Data Run to the end and assign new node
            if(originNode.headOfSubnode!=null)
            {
                newNode.nodeType = type | NodeTypes.TAIL;
                AppendToTail(type,GetEndOfBranch(originNode.headOfSubnode),newNode);
            }//Search for proper SubNodeTypes then add. Wicked Recursion warning here...
            else if((originNode.headOfSubnode.nodeType & type) != type)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Do Gnarly Search To Find!");
                return;
            }//Doesn't have subnode... add new Subnode.
            else
            {
                newNode.nodeType = type | NodeTypes.HEAD | NodeTypes.TAIL;
                originNode.headOfSubnode = newNode;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Add to the current branch
            newNode.nodeType = type | NodeTypes.TAIL;
            AppendToTail(type,GetEndOfBranch(originNode),newNode);
        }
    }

    private void AppendToTail(NodeTypes type,AchievementNode tailNode, AchievementNode newNode)
    {
        if((tailNode.nodeType & NodeTypes.HEAD) == NodeTypes.HEAD)
        {
            tailNode.nodeType = tailNode.nodeType | type;
        }
        else
        {
            tailNode.nodeType = type;
        }
        tailNode.nextOfType = newNode;
    }

    protected AchievementNode GetEndOfBranch(AchievementNode currentNode)
    {
        //Special Case where Node is HEAD and TAIL.
        if((currentNode.nextOfType.nodeType & NodeTypes.TAIL) != NodeTypes.TAIL)
        {
            return GetEndOfBranch(currentNode.nextOfType);
        }
        else
        {
            return currentNode;
        }
    }

    protected void SetType(NodeTypes type)
    {
        nodeType = type;
    }

    protected virtual AchievementNode FindInHierarchy(NodeTypes nodeCheck, AchievementNode currentNode)
    {
        if(currentNode == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else if((currentNode.nodeType & nodeCheck) == nodeCheck)
        {
            return currentNode;
        }
        else
        {
            return FindInHierarchy(nodeCheck,currentNode.nextOfType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a type of Priority Queue to me.

Comment: Just a side note: why do you `else` after a `return`? It is useless, `return` exits the code path.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a LinkedList meets Tree Structure. LinkedTree ?

Comment: I guess you could say that! @_@ I finished the implementation today and I'm really pleased with the tag based lookups. I'll end up posting the source soon. @fge What if that return is never hit?

Comment: @TylerDavidKirk well, the return is hit only if the condition is true; if it is not hit, the branch is not taken?

Comment: Oh man! I see exactly what you're saying now... That is a goof on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why do you have HEAD and TAIL NodeTypes? Doesn't their position on the branch tell you that?
2. I'm concerned that you have structure traversal code infused into `AchievementNode` class. Classically the structure - tree, queue, List, etc. - is independent of the objects it holds. I would think greatly upon using something like `Dictionary<T>`, `List<T>`, etc. *Use that structure's inherent reference/traversal features in the context of `NodeType`*. - wrapping (inheriting?) that structure along with your concept of `NodeType` into a class that is essentially a `MyNodes<AcheivementNode>` class. I wonder, is `MyNodes<NodeType>` what you are really building? In any case I suspect the separation of concerns will make the `NodeType` idea standout better conceptually and architecturally.
3. How many palaces do you have `NodeType` defined I wonder. Why is `NodeType` enum defined inside `AchievementNode`? That's unusual. You want it hidden from client code? I don't think so since you have method parameters of `NodeType`.

Comment: 1. The HEAD and TAIL NodeTypes are intended usage in the custom GUI that comes with it. I thought it would be quicker than searching the branch every time I wanted to see where it was on the branch. Aren't bitwise operations supposed to be super fast?

Comment: 2. You definitely made something click in my brain with this comment. I would really love to go back and refactor. It makes a lot more sense to isolate traversal methods in a generic class. That sounds incredibly reusable and flexible.

Comment: 3. NodeType is only defined within this class, as it only pertains to data that this class wants. It's referenced often but only internally for sorting and searching.